# Re-enabling Mouse Using Rundll32

Tags: batch-file

I have already disabled the mouse & keyboard using the

```
RUNDLL MOUSE,DISABLE
RUNDLL KEYBOARD,DISABLE
```

But I couldn't figure out how to enable it again w/o having to restart my computer.

Comment: Via `RUNDLL KEYBOARD,ENABLE` perhaps?

Comment: I have tried, but it didn't work

Comment: May I ask you how you tried this with both the mouse and keyboard disabled? How did you entered the `RUNDLL KEYBOARD,ENABLE` command?